# How to install pymedia?

Tags: python, windows, wrapper

I tried to install pymediainfo on my computer(I am using Python 3.6 and windows 8.1) and run the sample code of its webpage. (https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#requirements)
However, when I try to run it, I get this message:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Agusjacob96\Documents\video\New.py", line 2, in 
>       media_info = MediaInfo.parse(r'C:\Users\Agusjacob96\Documents\video\C0.mov')   File
>   "C:\Users\Agusjacob96\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymediainfo__init__.py",
>   line 93, in parse
>       lib = cls._get_library()   File "C:\Users\Agusjacob96\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymediainfo__init__.py",
>   line 76, in _get_library
>       return windll.MediaInfo   File "C:\Users\Agusjacob96\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ctypes__init__.py",
>   line 418, in **getattr**
>       dll = self._dlltype(name)   File "C:\Users\Agusjacob96\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ctypes__init__.py",
>   line 348, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado"

I already have installed Mediainfo on my computer, so the lib should be there. Could you help me, please?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ download the `whl` file then install using pip or other way.

Comment: @lapinkoira I installed the program from mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo then I opened command prompt and i wrote "pip install pymediainfo"